# Enable RBAC features in kibana alone

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, rbac

I want to create a new space in kibana and create a new user , attach a role with specific access and only to the space. This is a straight-forward thing with lot of docs provided by elasticsearch itself, but however there is one thing that I cannot find any clear documentation on. Does kibana support RBAC without enabling security features in elasticsearch? Is it possible to create roles in kibana without enabling security features in elasticsearch? I'm almost sure that it is not possible but since there is not direct wordings in the documents stating the above, I'm skeptical about it and hence posting here for expert suggestions.
I'm using kibana version 7.7.1. In my dashboard I'm not able to see the word "security" anywhere as described in the document. Posting a sample screenshot below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally Found an official document that states the same. To answer the question, Yes Kibana doesn't support RBAC in a standalone manner. It depends on elasticsearch.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.x/using-kibana-with-security.html

Comment: You can also check this out: https://readonlyrest.com/